# Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.coords.latitude')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Code:

```
const latitude = 19.0760;
const longitude = 72.8777;

state = {
        region: {
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE
        },
    };

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
         (position) => {
          var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
                this.setState({
                        initialRegion: {
                            latitude: initialPosition.coords.latitude,
                            longitude: initialPosition.coords.longitude,
                        }
                });
            },
        (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
```

I try to get lat and long value.but my code throws exception.where i went wrong?any help will appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you convert a JS object to string with `JSON.stringify` you cannot access the object values with dot or brackets notation

Try

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
     (position) => {
      var initialPosition = {
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                    }
            this.setState({
                    initialRegion: initialPosition
            });
        },
    (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
);
```

Comment: how to get lat and long value?

Answer (score 0):

> `(evaluating 'a.coords.latitude')',`

`a.coords.latitude` is not provided in the code sample so the error is not in the code you have posted

## Fix

Errors are generally printed with the stack trace. Please a breakpoint at the error location to see why `a` is undefined.